# Stream audio file from Web API 2 to client app without making a copy of the file client-side

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, audio-streaming

I'm having a little trouble conceptualizing how to play an audio file on a server via a client app through web API. Searching for some examples only yields me methods here or there, but nothing about file structure, etc. So essentially I'm looking for an example that begins with something like an AJAX call from the client to the API, and all the requisite methods involved in processing that.

Also, is it acceptable to work with these files by storing them in a folder in the Web API project?

Comment: are you asking about Web Audio API

Comment: No, I mean .net web API 2